# Practicing For Loop in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a for loop which appends the type of each element in the first list to the second list. Here is my code:

```py
lst1=[3.14, 66, "Teddy Bear", True, [], {}]
type = []

for i in lst1:
    typ = lst(type(i))
    type.append(typ)
    return type
```

However, I am getting an error in line 5

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Can anyone help me with a solution and explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: On line 2 you redefine `type` as a list. You should rename this variable as it overrides the function [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

Comment: You called your list `type`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what to point out first because there is a lot but see the following example, that does what you want, it may help you:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = []

for i in list1:
    list2.append(type(i))
```

I will add explanation of what's going on with your code in edit.

```
lst1=[3.14, 66, "Teddy Bear", True, [], {}]
type = [] # first of all you are shadowing a type built in function

for i in lst1:
    typ = lst(type(i)) # type method is not accessible anymore and python treats type as list now
    type.append(typ)
    return type # you are also returning from program witch is useless (maybe also invalid, I did not test)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `type(i)` please use index lookup `type[i]`

also type is a reserved keyword in python and should be avoided for variable names

Comment: I think that with `type(i)` he wanted to get the type of element i. So the brackets are right just he can not use `type` as a variable name

Comment: `type[i]` would definitely throw an error. Also, just a semantic point, but `type` is *not* a reserved keyword in Python, otherwise, *by definition, you wouldn't be able to use it as a variable name*

Comment: python shadows it imo `>>> type = [1,2,3]
>>> type[0]
1`

Answer (score 1):

Frist thing, avoid using variable name as `type`, it's a built in and not considered a good practice. And this is the reason why you are getting the error, because you are using `type` as a list variable, and later in the loop, trying to call `type`.

A more readable form would be the use of list-comprehension:

```py
lst1=[3.14, 66, "Teddy Bear", True, [], {}]
data_types = [type(item) for item in lst1]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'dict'>]
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: lst1=[3.14, 66, "Teddy Bear", True, [], {}]
data_types = [type(item) for item in lst1]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-42-539c1f9e7b0e>", line 2, in <module>
    data_types = [type(item) for item in lst1]

  File "<ipython-input-42-539c1f9e7b0e>", line 2, in <listcomp>
    data_types = [type(item) for item in lst1]

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: I ran it again, it's working fine... If you are getting error, add the error trace back to this  comment.

Comment: @hrishilaguha, don't use  `type = []` which is in your question, Read the answer again, I have mentioned not to use `type` as a variable name

Comment: yes its working now. Just needed to delete the user defined variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. Here is your script, with some changes:

```
values = [3.14, 66, "Teddy Bear", True, [], {}]

types = []

for value in values:
    types.append(type(value))

print(types)

del types  # start fresh

types = [type(value) for value in values]  # list comprehension

print(types)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are overwriting the `type` function with an empty list. Just give a different name to the list:

```py
lst1=[3.14, 66, "Teddy Bear", True, [], {}]
types = []

for i in lst1:
    types.append(type(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
o=[]
for i in list1:
   n=type(i)
   o.append(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension would do this nicely.

You can access the string that describes the "type" using the __ name __ attribute on the output of `type()`

```
list1 = [3.14, 66, "Teddy Bear", True, [], {}]
    
types = [type(i).__name__ for i in list1]
```

This gives you the output:

```
['float', 'int', 'str', 'bool', 'list', 'dict']
```

Comment: List function not callable is the error I am still getting

Comment: Try running the above code in a new Python session. It should work so long as you're not using ```type``` as a variable name as you have in your original question (this overwrites the python function ```type```)